# Laravel Nova - 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a problem with Laravel Nova, it is very weird and it happen suddenly.

When I enter to /nova/login. Perfect, I log in and plaf, error 404.
I try to enter to a resource by URL /nova/resources/blabla-nova. And guess, it works, but if I refresh this page, guess, error 404.

Another issue, or I guess it is an issue, is the view of error 404. It error is from Laravel's view (just 404 | Error) and it doesn't show the 404 error from Nova (with images, text, bla bla).

I tried the next:

- php artisan route:cache
- php artisan cache:clear
- uninstall laravel nova and install again
- remove vendor / composer.lock and composer update
- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan optimize
- verify config/app.php for Laravel Nova Provider
- php artisan route:list --name=nova.index and it shows correctly

So, I don't what do to.

I'm using:

- Laravel 7.27.0
- Laravel Nova 3.x

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
If I inspect on Network tab, just Resources and views I get Error 404.

[image]

```
"message": "No query results for model [App\\Category] nova-api",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you reload the page with ctrl + F5?

Comment: Error 404 with if I reload the page with button, keyboard, anything.

Comment: Can you post the entire endpoint that is causing the 404 error ?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: If you still have this issue check the middleware settings in `config/nova.php`. You can also check if the admin path is set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You might be passing empty or undefined category id to category resource.
Your error indicates that it is trying to retrieve record from database for category table but is not able to identity category id passed to the query.

Try loading Initial dashboard page of your nova application or check your model path in respective resource file.
Eg: I store model files in App\Models\Category

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).